# How to have a builder return instances of different subtypes?

Tags: scala

```
class Dog(name:String, age:Int) { def bark() = "woof" }

// complex dog builder
object DogBuilder {
   def  complexBuilder(name: String, age:Int) = 
       {new Dog(name + "A", age-1)}
}

// type Special identical constructor parameters, but has extra method
 class SpecialDog(name:String, age:Int) extends Dog(name:String, age:Int)      
 { def special_dog() = "special"}}
```

What modifications do I make to `complex_builder` so that it can return instances of `SpecialDog` as well? How do I tell the compiler "it is OK, Dog and SpecialDog have the same arguments, so it is OK to use the same complexBuilder, but return SpecialDog or Dog". I understand `complexBuilder` will have to change in some fashion, but..how/what?

what I want is something like (psedo-code)

```
object DogBuilder {
    // a function that translates the inputs in some complex fashion
   def complexRules {(String, Int) => (String, Int)

    def  specialDog: specaalDog = new SpecialDog(..uses complexRules)
    def  regularDog: Dog = new Dog(..resuses same complexRules)


val specialDog: specialDog  = DogBuilder.specialDog("D", 5)
val dog: Dog= DogBuilder.regularDog("D", 5)
```

And of course that won't work because of type erasure, but what is the best thing to mimic the above?

Comment: Wait, so should complex_builder (btw correct naming convention in Scala is complexBuilder) return a Dog or a SpecialDog? Types will be easy to align, but I don't see what you're trying to do here. When I invoke `DogBuilder.complexBuilder("name", 42)`, am I getting a `Dog` or a `SpecialDog`? Or you want the returned type to depend on the type parameter?

Comment: Yes, I want the returned type to depend on the type parameter..but [because] the types that I will be passing all have the same constructor arguments [i.e SpecialDog does NOT add extra argument], I want all these types to go thru complexBuilder. complexBuilder code should be the same for all types, it returns different type [Dog or SuperDog]

Comment: You want to be able to do `val dog: Dog = DogBuilder.complexBuilder("name", 12)` and get a Dog, as well as  `val dog: SpecialDog = DogBuilder.complexBuilder("name", 12)` and get a SpecialDog?

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me. What if I just do `val dog = DogBuilder.complexBuilder("name", 12)`? What do I get?

Comment: What is the return type of `DogBuilder.complexBuilder("a", 2)`? Do you want to be able to do something like `DogBuilder.complexBuilder[Dog]("a", 2)` and `DogBuilder.complexBuilder[SpecialDog]("a", 2)`? Don't worry about code, just explain your requirements in plain english :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is a really poorly formed question. Sorry mate. It's just full of errors, typos, it cannot compile even remotely (I see things such as double brackets from a mile away).

I *think* this is what you want, although I have no idea what it would have to do with type erasure. To me it seems like you want to apply the complexFunction to parameters before creating an instance of the class.

```
class Dog(name: String, age: Int) {
  def bark() = "woof"
}

class SpecialDog(name: String, age: Int) extends Dog(name: String, age: Int) {
  def special_dog() = "special"
}

object DogBuilder {

  def complexRules(s: String, i: Int) = (s + "a", i + 1)

  def dog(name: String, age: Int): Dog = {
    val (newName, newAge) = complexRules(name, age)
    new Dog(newName, newAge)
  }

  def specialDog(name: String, age: Int): SpecialDog = {
    val (newName, newAge) = complexRules(name, age)
    new SpecialDog(newName, newAge)
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. be able to apply the same function as constructor arguments. This really helped, thank you.  [I had mentioned type erasure because I had previously been going the route of a generic function that could return Dog or SuperDog]. I will check this out and click the green thing

Comment: No problem. If you want to avoid being closed as unclear, make sure to state your problem clearly and to provide us with [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).